# How do you set Evince as the default document viewer in Kubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

When I open a PDF it opens by default in Okular. How do I make Evince the default viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right click the PDF document and select "Open with", find Evince in the list (or manually if it's not there) then check the "Remember application association for this type of file". I don't have a KDE desktop in front of me at the moment but that should be roughly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In GNOME: right click on a PDF file and choose properties. In the pop up that shows there's a tab called "Open With": choose the application you prefer (Evince is called: Document Viewer), and click the "set as default" button at the bottom right. Now you're all set :)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020: Right click on your PDF file. Then scroll down to "Open With", and then click "Other...". You should first click the box that says "Remember application association for all files of type 'PDF document'". Finally,search for Document Viewer, which also opens the PDF files identically as Evince, and click OK. That should do it.